# C++ File help, Encrypting and Decrypting String

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I'm trying to make a simple program that modifies the values by 3 (Encrypt function) ->I want this to directly affect the file. But I'm not sure how. After it's encrypted I will call the Decrypt function (which works exactly how I want it to) This way you will have to run the program to access the diary. Is there anyway I can modify the individual characters like I do in the decrypt function? I keep getting a getline error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void decrypt_diary(string,string);
void encrpyt_diart(string,string);

int main()
{
    string fileName = "Diary.txt";
    string line;
    decrypt_diary(fileName,line);
    return 0;
}
void decrypt_diary(string fileName, string line)
{
    ifstream journal;
    journal.open(fileName);
    if (journal.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(journal,line))
        {
            for (int i=0; i<signed(line.length()); i++)
            {
                line[i] = line[i] + 3;
            }
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
    journal.close();
}

void encrypt_diary(string fileName, string line)
{
    ofstream journal;
    journal.open(fileName);
    if (journal.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(journal,line))
        {
            for (int i=0; i<signed(line.length()); i++)
            {
                line[i] = line[i] - 3;
//              journal << line[i];
            }
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
    journal.close();
}
```

Comment: You could use an `fstream`, read a character, change it, write it back to the same position, if that's what you really want to do. But I'd say it should be much faster if you read the entire file into memory, modify it and then write the whole thing back to the file. Unless the file won't fit in memory, then do so in chunks.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by read the entire file into memory, maybe you can elaborate. Oh and yes, that first way is the way I intended to write it. I just don't know how to go about that process. I'd prefer that way atm as I'm just learning about <fstream>

Comment: Open the file in read/write mode and prepare for a read/seek/write orgy.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the getline error you mean?

> ./main.cpp:41:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::ofstream&, std::__cxx11::string&)’
>            while (getline(journal,line)

If so, I believe the issue is that there is no *getline()* function that takes an *ofstream* object, as *getline()* is for reading files while *ofstream (output file stream)* is for writing files. It works fine in the *decrypt_diary* function as that takes an *ifstream (input file stream)*.

If you focus on implementing either decrypt or encrypt first, you'll have an easier time resolving compile issues.

You can try to comment out the *encrypt_diary(string fileName, string line)* function, then try to compile and run the program again.

I think you'll find that your *decrypt_diary(string fileName, string line)* function works fine.

Comment: ah, thank you for explaining why the getline() didn't work for the ofstream, that makes a lot of sense. And yes I knew that the decrypt_diary(string fileName, string line) function worked fine. I'm currently working on a round about way to get the other function to do what I want without it having to read the file as that's not what ofstream does. I'll post a solution once I've put one together. Again thanks so much for that explanation, on the streams business, it helped solidify what I was thinking

Comment: That makes sense. I misunderstood a little bit then. If you need a stream for both writing and reading, you can try to use the fstream.

As @Qubit mentioned in a comment on your question, reading the entire file into memory (for example a string variable), then manipulating this data, before writing it back into a file, is likely the easiest way to handle encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand what you want correctly, you want to go through the file, character by character and replace it with some other character. I will again state that going character by character is probably not the best idea, but the modification to chunks should be simple enough.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

inline void encrypt_char(char& in) {
    in += 3;
}

inline void decrypt_char(char& in) {
    in -= 3;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //These first 2 lines just process the command line argument
    if (argc < 2 || (argv[1][0] != 'e' && argv[1][0] != 'd') || argv[1][1] != '\0') return 1;
    bool encrypt_mode = (argv[1][0] == 'e' ? true : false);
    std::fstream file("Diary.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = file.tellg(); //This should tell us the file size
    char c;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        file.seekg(i, std::ios::beg); //Set read position
        file.read(&c, 1); //Read a character
        if (encrypt_mode) encrypt_char(c);
        else decrypt_char(c);
        file.seekp(i, std::ios::beg); //Set write position
        file.write(&c, 1); //Write a character
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that we avoid using `>>` and `<<` as they are formatted, skip whitespaces by default (although you can change that) etc. Instead we use `read` and `write` since they just store the bytes, whatever those bytes may be.

This approach means we do loads of operations on the file and is probably not the fastest. Instead, you can read in chunks, that modification is quite simply, simply replace the character with a character array and read more than 1 byte at a time. If possibly however, it might be easiest to read the entire file at once.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

inline void encrypt_char(char& in) {
    in += 3;
}

inline void decrypt_char(char& in) {
    in -= 3;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //These first 2 lines just process the command line argument
    if (argc < 2 || (argv[1][0] != 'e' && argv[1][0] != 'd') || argv[1][1] != '\0') return 1;
    bool encrypt_mode = (argv[1][0] == 'e' ? true : false);
    std::fstream file("Diary.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = file.tellg(); //This should tell us the file size
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    char* fileData = new char[size]; //Don't need null-termination
    file.read(fileData, size); //Read the whole file
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) { //Process the characters
        if (encrypt_mode) encrypt_char(fileData[i]);
        else decrypt_char(fileData[i]);
    }
    file.seekp(0, std::ios::beg); //Find the start of the file
    file.write(fileData, size); //Write the whole thing
    delete[] fileData;
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Calling the program with `./myProgram e` causes it to encrypt, replacing the `e` with a `d` causes it to decrypt.

We didn't use strings here, since we don't really need them, but you can always do so if you prefer strings to character arrays.

This of course is a fairly simple example, you are free to modify and complicate it as you wish. Also note that it is probably not the only (nor possibly the best) way to deal with such problems.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, this helps a ton!!! This is the first question I've asked in fear that I'm being stupid, but I honestly don't care after this. This community is very smart, and thanks for helping me learn. I had a problem with ./myProgram e it compiles and but when I type that I get this error. ./diary.cpp: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./diary.cpp: line 5: `inline void encrypt_char(char& in) {'

Comment: Uhh, you don't want to run the source code, you want to run the executable. I don't know whether you're on Linux or Windows nor do I know what you named the executable? You can just use whatever parts of the code you wish in your own project, it does not need to parse command line arguments if you're not familiar with that. There's no reason to try and learn too many things at once, focus on one, then move on to the other.

Comment: I just wanted to make an update. Your code worked no problem, it was an issue on my side.